# working 14.04 ubuntu to error: no such device: grub rescue>

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, mount, gpt

I'm a father and I was trying to get one more entry on gnucash after my youngest woke up.  I had gnucash, keypass, chrome and LibreOffice calc up when my son found the power button....  Nooooooo!  :D

When I restarted Ubuntu I was met with the following:

> Error: no such device...
>   grub rescue>

I don't think the system was updating and only other software that could be running was CrashPlan.

Below is my initial attempt

```
grub rescue> ls

(hd0)
```

There is no partition recognized…  I tried to change the directory to hd0, but couldn’t (no something something)

Then I started Ubuntu up in Live CD mode by “trying Ubuntu” from my original installation CD.
I ran Boot Info Script by downloading it from **bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net**
Extracting using the default extractor (not the terminal)

Then in the terminal I wrote:

```
Sudo ~/Downloads/bootinfoscript
```

The result is posted below.

```
                 Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000203804160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953523055 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,046 1,953,521,663 1,953,519,618   5 Extended
/dev/sda5               2,048 1,953,521,663 1,953,519,616  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda5        bf1747fe-86af-43af-89fe-80a261162823   ext4       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS amd64

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda5        /media/ubuntu/bf1747fe-86af-43af-89fe-80a261162823 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

  No volume groups found
```

Then I tried boot-repair by entering in the terminal:

```
Sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I did the “recommended repair”

Results are posted on the below link:

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/16662512/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

But it started up in the Grub rescue mode again.

I’m a little stubborn and want to do things myself… so then I typed in the terminal of grub rescue

```
Grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
Grub rescue> set root=(hd0,1)
Grub rescue> insmod normal
```

No something something.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000203804160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953523055 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004c7e9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2046  1953521663   976759809    5  Extended
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5            2048  1953521663   976759808   83  Linux

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1   250069679   125034839+  ee  GPT
```

```
sudo parted -l
```

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00K (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1048kB  1000GB  1000GB  extended               boot
 5      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  logical   ext4


Model: ATA TS128GSSD340 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB  100GB   ext4
 2      100GB   128GB  28.0GB  linux-swap(v1)


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

Next this is what I typed into the terminal:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/ubuntu/temp/
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp/ /dev/sdb1
```

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) – try one of the manual methods. For whatever reason BootRepair both detects and later doesn't detect an existing Grub installation on your hard drive and doesn't offer to repair it.

Comment: Okay... I fixed it with the above.  Apparently I just needed to restart after the last bit.  Thought I did that.  Not sure if there is any thing I need to fix, but I think the original boot repair did it?  I'm debating leaving or deleting this post - I'll leave it for others to decide.    Thanks Hizqeel for editing my post.

Comment: **Duplicate as per comments above**